# Artisan CLI 3.2 confused

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I am trying to setup a cronjob to be run everyday on a shared hosting (Bluehost) (PHP 5.3).

My website is built on laravel 3.2.
I understand I need to run it with the Artisan CLI.

Logged in with SSH, I tried any artisan commands and it always return 'sorry, I can't find that task'.

```
php-cli artisan list
```

// can't find that task
    php-cli artisan --version
 // same
    php-cli artisan command:make Whateva
 // same

Do I have the wrong command names or what?

Comment: Is there even a list of commands for Artisan 3.2 ?? The new website is all about version 4..

Answer (score 0):

I'm confuse, `php-cli artisan command:make` is Laravel 4 specific. See http://three.laravel.com/docs/artisan/commands for Laravel 3 documentation.